# How to get the product name with the highest value by month?

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-8

I'm trying to display a data by month and displays the product with the highest value or bought quantity. But I don't know how I should do it.

This is the code I have and tried so far

```
public function viewSales(){
   
    $data = sales::select(
        [sales::raw("SUM(product_fee) as product_fee, MONTHNAME(created_at) as month_name, MAX(bought) as bought"),'product']
    )->whereYear('created_at', date("Y"))
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('month_name')
    ->get();
     return view('admin.viewSales', compact('data'));
}
```

This is what's inside my database

| id | product | bought | product_fee | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dictionary | 1 | 200 | 2023-01-14 18:55:34 |
| 2 | Horror | 3 | 100 | 2023-01-15 17:55:34 |
| 3 | How to cook | 5 | 300 | 2023-01-16 11:55:34 |

and this is what I'm trying to display

| Most bought product | sold | overall earning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| How to cook | 5 | 600 |

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please tell me where the 600 overall earning comes from?

Comment: Hello, it is from ```SUM(product_fee) as product_fee```

Comment: or the column ```product_fee``` ... it's supposed to be ```paid``` but I still haven't changed it. Which I'm trying to get the total sum and will serve as **overall earning**

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this :

```
public function viewSales(){
   
    $data = sales::select(
        [sales::raw("(bought*product_fee) as overall_earning, MONTHNAME(created_at) as month_name, MAX(bought) as bought"),'product']
    )->whereYear('created_at', date("Y"))
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('month_name')
    ->get();
     return view('admin.viewSales', compact('data'));
}
```

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL will give you the  desired output for current year and month.

Fetch for current year

```
SELECT 
  product as most_bought_product_for_the_year,
  bought as sold, 
  (SELECT SUM(product_fee) from products WHERE YEAR(created_at) = year(curdate())) as overall_earning 
FROM `products` 
WHERE 
  bought = (SELECT MAX(bought) from products WHERE YEAR(created_at) = year(curdate()));
```

Fetch for months of the current year

```
SELECT
  product as most_bought_for_the_month,
  bought as sold,
  MONTHNAME(created_at) as month_name,
  SUM(product_fee) as overall_earning
FROM `products` 
WHERE 
  YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(curdate())
AND 
  bought IN (SELECT MAX(bought) from products WHERE YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(curdate()) GROUP by MONTH(created_at))
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
ORDER BY MONTH(created_at);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ded2ae9/8)